# d3js, chained method confusion

Tags: d3.js

```
var s = selectAll().data(); 
s.enter()
  .append();

//how is this different from:

var s = selectAll().data()
  .enter()
  .append();
```

when I call `update()` for the first time, the `data.links` and `data.nodes` updates their `x,y`s just fine.
But the svg elements don't even bother to include `x,y` attributes.

And if I join the data `links.selectAll("line").data(data.links);` one more time, it seems to have 'solved' the issue.

```
//full code here.
function update(){
  link = links.selectAll("line")
    .data(data.links); // NOTE: here I didn't chain data.
  link.enter().append("line")
    .style("stroke", function(d){return "#3498db";})
    .style("opacity", 0.7)
    .style("stroke-width", 1); //enter
  link.exit().remove(); //exit

  node = nodes.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.nodes);  // NOTE: here I didn't chain data.
  node.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", "#3498db")
    .attr("id", function(d){return d.id;})
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended)); //enter
  node.exit().remove(); //exit

  simulation
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);
  simulation.force("link")
    .links(data.links);
  simulation.restart();
}
```

Comment: In your first snippet you have an "update" and an "enter" selections. In the second one you have only the "enter" selection.

Comment: I chose that question to close as duplicate but there are actually many of them here at S.O explaining the difference. Just search "update enter selection".